# R encountered a fatal error, This session was terminated When using write.xlsx append

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I try to write a df to an existing excel file by using write.xlsx(df, filename.xlsx, sheetName=123, append=TRUE). After run the code two times, R studio encountered a fatal error, and I have to uninstall Rsudio and reinstall it. But I still have the same problem after re-installation.

If I write the df to a new excel file by write.xlsx(df, name.xlsx, sheetName = 123, col.names = TRUE), the code will be totally fine. No such problem ever.

Anyone can tell me how to solve this problem? I appreciate!

Comment: What library do you use? Is your dataframe big enough to crash RStudio, or it is small? Have you tried to give Java more memory?

Comment: @AlexeyKnorre Iuse library(xlsx)

Comment: `xlsx` is (r)java-dependent and it causes a lot of headache with heap space etc. In my experience it's always better to use Java-independent libraries (`readxl` for reading, `openxlsx` for writing). Try `openxlsx` library, it seems much more reliable, think it will solve your problem.

Comment: @AlexeyKnorre Thank you! Will try!

Comment: @AlexeyKnorre Now I have this new problem, https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/76. Have you ever had the same problem.

Comment: Yep. The problem is that openxlsx needs zip archiver, which is bundled with RTools. To install the latter, do this:
`install.packages("installr")`
`installr::install.rtools()`
That should do.